# Export Project to DXF dialog using Python

Tags: pyqgis, export, dxf, qgis-python-console

I'm trying to run 'Export Project to DXF' in QGIS using the Python console.
The intention is to export multiple vector layers, as defined by a Theme Visibility State, in the same way as if you utilized the standard dialog box.

I've written some code based on other posts and the `qgisapp.cpp`, but I'm stuck trying to input multiple layers in the theme to `QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer`.

The code below will halt because the output of `lyr_names` is a list, does `DxfLayer` even support multiple inputs?

Any ideas?

```
dxfExport = QgsDxfExport()
lyr_names = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection().mapThemeVisibleLayers('Theme_Name')]
dxfExport.setMapSettings( settings )
dxfExport.addLayers( [QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer(lyr_names)] )
dxfExport.setSymbologyScale(200)
dxfExport.setSymbologyExport(1)
dxfExport.setLayerTitleAsName(-1)
dxfExport.setDestinationCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:28356"))
dxfExport.setForce2d(0)
dxfExport.setExtent(new_box)

dxfFile = QFile('C:/Temp/plots/test2.dxf')
dxfExport.writeToFile( dxfFile, 'CP1252' )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Does `DxfLayer` even support multiple inputs?*

No. The error `QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer(QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'` states that, explicitly.

But you can use

```
dxfExport.addLayers([QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer(lyr) for lyr in lyr_names])
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Kadir is correct, but can work too if you don't want to create any Map Theme:

```
[...]
dxfExport.addLayers([QgsDxfExport.DxfLayer(lyr) for lyr in prj.mapLayers().values()])
[...]
```

This will retrieve all the layers stored in the instance.